# How to propagate Spring Security Context in Spring Integration async messaging gateway

Tags: spring-security, spring-integration

I am trying to get spring security context to propagate through an spring integration async message flow, but have found that even though I added `SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor` the security context always ends up null in my message handler.

```
@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = {"*"})
public ChannelInterceptor securityContextPropagationInterceptor()
{
    return new SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor();
}
```

I initiate my flow from a service that has a populated security context by making a call to my gateway interface:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface AssignmentsService
{
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "applyAssignmentsFlow.input")
    ListenableFuture<AssignmentResult> applyAssignments( AssignmentRequest assignmentRequest );
}
```

On further debugging I have found that the `GatewayProxyFactoryBean` creates a new thread when initiating my flow, but does not propagate the security context.

I have searched but have been unable to find out how to configure this to propagate the security context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty interesting task. Indeed :) !

But anyway you can do it like this:

```
@Bean
public AsyncTaskExecutor securityContextExecutor() {
    return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
}

...

@MessagingGateway(asyncExecutor = "securityContextExecutor")
public interface AssignmentsService
```

The main trick here is from Spring Security and its concurrency [utils](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrency), where we should use `TaskExecutor` wrappers to pick up the current `SecurityContext` and propagate it into newly spawned Thread.

There is nothing about Spring Integration, though - just the proper way to work with Security.

Will add such a trick into Reference Manual soon.

Pull request on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2015

Comment: Hi! This almost worked, except I found I had to subclass `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` as it did not implement `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor` interface. Should I raise a change request with the Spring Security Team to change it to implement the `AsyncListenableTaskExecutor`?

Comment: Yes, please: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues.